# `ElasticsearchOperations` formulation with spring-data-elasticsearch 4.4 and elasticsearch 7.16

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Before elasticsearch 7.16, the `ElasticsearchOperations` could be formulated with `RestHighLevelClient`

```
    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() {
        try {
            RestClientBuilder restClientBuilder = RestClient.builder(httpHosts)
                  .setHttpClientConfigCallback(httpClientBuilder -> httpClientBuilder
                        .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(getElasticCredentialsProvider())
                        .setKeepAliveStrategy((response, context) -> 3 * 60 * 1000));
            return new ElasticsearchRestTemplate(restHighLevelClient);
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Now that RestHighLevelClient is deprecated, I couldn't find a new class to get elasticsearch operations from the new [Java client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/7.16/introduction.html) provided.

The dependencies in play are

```
    spring_elasticsearch = 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-elasticsearch:4.4.0-M2'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am currently working on integrating the new Elasticsearch client in Spring Data Elasticsearch. We will in the next minor release (4.4) still the `RestHighLevelClient` but provide as an optional alternative the possibility to use the new client.

The new client does not yet have the same functionality as the RHLC and still has some error (you might want to have a look at [it's issue list](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-java/issues)), so we cannot already replace it, but the most important reason not to use it in the current version is that the new Client pulls in `jakarta` packages instead of `javax` and switching by default to the new client would break many existing applications.

A full replacement cannot be done before Spring Data Elasticsearch 5.0, which will use Spring 6, be integrated in Spring Boot 3 as Jakarta EE9 will be only with these releases.

In my opinion, Elasticsearch should not have deprecated the RHLC in a switch of a minor version (ES 7.15 -> 7.16) while providing an incomplete alternative that introduces breaking changes.

So for the time being we have to live with the fact that Spring Data Elasticsearch needs to use a deprecated class.